# Horizontal Overflow Scroll Not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the horizontal scroll work on a div. I have a container with multiple floating boxes within, but if i do overflow-x: auto, it doesn't work.

What i want is that the .product-container should be aligned horizontally. Right now it is falling down due to the float:left attribute.

The html structure is:

```
    <div class="category-container">
        <div class="product-list">
            <div class="product-container">
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The css styling is as follows

```
<style>
        .category-container{
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 235px;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            /*border-right-style: solid;*/
            background-color: white;
            border-width: 1px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            position: relative;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .product-list{
            overflow-x:auto;
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 190px;
        }

        .product-container{
            width: 230px;
            min-height: 200px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            margin-left:10px;
            border-color: grey;
            padding-bottom:10px;
        }
 </style>
```

The JsFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/arj196/aY9BJ/

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: [Working](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/aY9BJ/1/) Your width is lesser . So it doesn't need to scroll. See now

Comment: You have a weird code as you are using `absolute` positioning for no good reason, your boxes are overflowing vertically but you need horizontal scrolling

Comment: I need the div.product-container to not fall down. i need them to be arranged horizontally. right now due to the float:left, it just falls when not enough width space.

Answer (score 1):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/aY9BJ/1/)

```
  .product-list
 {
   width: calc(100% - 50px);
   overflow-x:auto;
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 190px;
  }
```

Set width to product-list. If it requires scrolling , it ll add scrollbar since you specified overflow:auto;

Comment: Same demo as in my comment

Comment: I probably didn't properly explain myself, i modified my question, please review again

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `width=100%` to `.product-list` `class`. It will work then. It did not have enough width to have the scroll bar, and the inner `div` was being pushed down.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/aY9BJ/4/)

Give the appropriate `width`.

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust the width of .productList to what you want.

a working example:

```
      .product-list{
        width:300px;
        overflow-x:auto;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 190px;
    }
http://jsfiddle.net/xE6Pe/1/
```

Answer (score -1):

you need change `overflow-x: auto;` in `scrol`l and set `width:100%` in.`product-list` container

Comment: horizontal scroll means overflow-x. Isnt?

Comment: sorry not in a hurry about that wrote and in overflow-x: auto; or scroll and set width:100% in.product-list container

Comment: This is what i commented initially at the ques itself

Comment: wrote that same hurry

Comment: Okay then modify the code. Who downvotes this answer may remove it

Comment: well, or those who have more power